# Shopify check if Metafield exists?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm looking to hide content if the metafields are empty for a product, but right now it's returning it for all pages which means my if statement is broken somewhere.

**Product Page**

```
{% if product.metafields.review %}
  {% include 'extra-review' %}
{% else %}
{% endif %}
```

**Review Snippet Page (extra-review.liquid)**

```
{% assign review = product.metafields.review %}
{% assign key = 'author' %}
{% assign key = 'author-img' %}
{% assign key = 'long' %}

<p> Hello world </p>
```

Any help would be brilliant

EDIT

Added review metafields layout

[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To check if a namespace exists you can do a comparison against `blank`. For example:

```
{% if product.metafields.review != blank %}
  ...
{% endif %}
```

You could also used the `size` if you wanted to ensure you had three keys. Here we simply output the size:

```
{{ product.metafields.review.size }}
```

More info on truthy/falsy can be found in the Shopify docs:
https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/basics/true-and-false

Comment: Worked like an absolute charm - thanks very much @Jason

Comment: Can this be used for the *value* of metafields? 
`{% if product.metafields.review.value != blank %}`

Answer (score 3):

Truthiness in Liquid is not like Javascript. I've been bitten by this a few times:

Your test should be:

```
{% if product.metafields.review == true %}
...
{% endif %}
```

and `review` in  `product.metafields.review` is the namespace of the review metafields. see https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/objects/metafield

Comment: This seems to be removing the code even when the metafields exist for the current product?

Comment: Are you using the right namespace? See my edited answer

Comment: Added my metafields namespace table to the question. They're all under reviews, checked a product with the metafields existing, but they still don't appear :(